# squid will not listen on specific IP

Tags: squid

I have a public subnet with squid installed.

Let's say my subnet is from 1.2.3.2 to 1.2.4.254.

When I set the following:

```
http_port 50000
http_port 1.2.3.2:50000
```

it is working.

But when I set:

```
http_port 1.2.4.37:50000
```

it is not working.

It is only working with my first public IP from my subnet.

The error I get when it is not working is the following:

```
commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 10 to 1.2.4.37:50000: (99) Cannot assign requested address
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

**@Zoredache**

I have a dedicated server and the whole subnet is defined as IP Range.
When I use only the port or the first IP and doing

```
netstat -ntlp | grep  46555
```

I get the following:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25532/(squid        )
```

When I use my specific IP, then the netstat query will show nothing, as the server does not start.
I don't want squid to listen on all or the first IP, it is just a specific one it should listen to.

Comment: `the whole subnet is defined as IP Range`.  How exactly did you accomplish that.  Have you actually assigned every address to the computer, or has it just been routed to the computer.  Is `1.2.4.37` listed within the output of `ip addr`?

Comment: I get: `inet 1.2.3.2/22 brd 1.2.5.255 scope global eth0`. I transfered the original IPs to my above example for privacy reasons. Maybe the IP is not correctly transfered, but the `/22` is shown. So it should be assigned I think.

Comment: If the host hasn't been configured to have the `1.2.4.37` IP address then it doesn't have it.  You MUST configure it within the network settings.  Squid cannot bind to an IP that hasn't been configured on the host.

Comment: I thought when configuring the IP with my subnet mask, all IPs are configured. It shows the /22, so I think it has the whole subnet? Or will I need to assign every IP one by one?

Comment: No setting a subnet mask does not automatically assign all the addresses to the system.  The subnet mask is used for making a routing decision, so your computer knows what address space is local, and what isn't.

Comment: When entering ifconfig it shows
`inet Address:X.X.X.2  Bcast:X.X.X.255  Mask:255.255.252.0`
So what will I need to do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the output of `netstat -ntlp | grep 50000`?

By default the `http_port 50000` option will result in squid binding to `0.0.0.0:50000`  which means it will accept requests on any address on the system.

You shouldn't need to list `1.2.3.2`, or `1.2.4.37`.  Just make sure those addresses are assigned to the host.

If your host doesn't have the `1.2.4.37` address assigned locally, then I would gather you are trying to do interception caching or something.  You probably need to intercept that address with a firewall rule.  On a Linux system you would do this with REDIR.

> ip addr - I get: inet 1.2.3.2/22 brd 1.2.5.255 scope global eth0.

If the host hasn't been configured to have the `1.2.4.37` IP address then it doesn't have it.  You MUST configure it within the network settings.  Squid cannot bind to an IP that hasn't been configured on the host.

Comment: I have answered you in my question.